# How to alternate output between two lists?

Tags: python, list

I am trying to output which card a player gets as the card is being handed out. My idea was to output each card by alternating from the two lists. I have included an example below.

```
Ex.
List1 = [Banana,Cherry,Orange,Apple,Tomato]
List2 = [Blue,Red,Orange,Yellow,Grey,Purple]

Output:

    Banana
    Blue
    Cherry
    Red
    Orange
    Yellow...
```

This is what I have so far.

```
for card in player_A:
    print("Player A is dealt= ",card,"")
for card in Player_B:
    print("Player B is dealt=",card,"")
```

How can I go about doing that?

Answer (score 2):

Use [zip](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_zip.asp) to alternate between the two lists.

```
for a, b in zip(List1, List2):
  print(f'Player A is dealt= {a}')
  print(f'Playber B is dealt= {b}')
```

**Output**

```
Player A is dealt= Banana
Playber B is dealt= Blue
Player A is dealt= Cherry
Playber B is dealt= Red
Player A is dealt= Orange
Playber B is dealt= Orange
Player A is dealt= Apple
Playber B is dealt= Yellow
Player A is dealt= Tomato
Playber B is dealt= Grey
```

Comment: where is `Purple`?

Comment: @TenaciousB--in this case one list is longer than the other.  zip will alternate effectively handling out the same number to both people.  If we used zip_longest it will run until both lists are exhausted, giving the person with the shorter list "None" (or specified default value) for the unmatched values.

Comment: just wanted to make sure they are aware it will not return all the elements if they are different lengths (if that was their intention)

Answer (score -1):

You can just do

```
for i in range(len(List1)):
    print("Player A is dealt= ", List1[i], "")
    print("Player B is dealt= ", List2[i], "")
```

Comment: what if the lists have different lengths?

Comment: If different sizes cannot be printed alternately.